# Why we use @Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' }) to reach class?

Tags: angular

*I have a custom class to create custom validator. to use that validator in FormGroup I do like this:*

```
@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
export class MatchPassword {

}
```

in another class

```
import { MatchPassword } from '../validators/match-password';

export class SignupComponent implements OnInit {
  authForm = new FormGroup(
    {
      username: new FormControl('')
    },
    {
      validators: [this.match.validate],
    }
  );

  constructor(private match: MatchPassword) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {}
}
```

*why I dont use like*

> const object = new MatchPssword();

*to create an instance ?*

Comment: It is due to Angular dependency injection mechanism. It is a broad topic to discuss here. You could start from here: https://angular.io/guide/dependency-injection

Comment: I recommend you to dive into some design patterns, like the singleton. Those Angular practices start making more sense when you study them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to create an instance, you need to re-use an instance that your component depends on, and that the framework created at the startup.

You couldn't share information between components using `new`, instead, thanks to dependency injection, you can do something like this:

```
@Injectable({provideIn: 'root'})
export class MyService() {
  object: T = null;
  save(object: T) {
    this.object = object;
  }

  retrieve(): T {
    return this.object;
  }
}
```

And you can use `save` in a component and `retrieve` in another component, limiting the coupling.

Using `new`, instead, you would get two instances of `MyService.object`. In this case, services are very similar to singletons, but they're not singletons since they're managed by the framework and not by the developer.